# Preserve custom dtype when creating NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

For compatibility with legacy software, I need to create a NumPy array with dtype

```py
np.dtype("(2,)u8")
```

(i.e., an array of tuples of two `u8` integers each). When creating such an array, NumPy automatically converts the array to an array of shape `(4,2)` with dtype `u8` though:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.empty(4, dtype=np.dtype("(2,)u8"))

print(a.shape, a.dtype)
```

```
(4, 2) uint64
```

Any way to prevent that? Explicitly changing the dtype afterwards would also work.

Comment: you may need to show how this software depends on that dtype.

Comment: Are you sure that was a custom dtype?  As opposed to an object dtype, with tuple elements?  A structured array displays as a list of tuples, as is its input, but that's mainly to  distinguish it from a regular ndarray.

Comment: You can make a named field like `a=np.zeros(4,[('x','(2,)u8')])`; but a['x']` will still be (4,2).  Or `np.zeros(4,'u8,u8')` which displays a list of two element tuples.  In a structured array, a tuple wraps a record with one or more fields.